# Java - Reading text file as an integer and split each line into Array

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have text file like that :

```
1  2
1  4
1  5
2  3
2  6
3  6
4  5
4  7
5  7
7  8
7  9
8  10
9  10
```

So I want to split each integer and put into Array

```
        Path objPath = Paths.get("graph.txt");
        if (Files.exists(objPath)){

            File objFile = objPath.toFile();
            try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(objFile))){
                String line = in.readLine();

                while(line != null){


                    String[] stringArray = line.split("\\s+");
                    int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
                        String numberAsString = stringArray[i];
                        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
                    }
                    BridgeInGraph graph_obj = new BridgeInGraph(11);
                    graph_obj.add_edges_to_vertex(intArray[0], intArray[1]);
                    graph_obj.add_edges_to_vertex(intArray[2], intArray[3]);
                    .
                    .
                    .

                    System.out.println("Bridges in  Graphs ");
                    graph_obj.getCutVertices();
                    System.out.println("Points:");
                    graph_obj.AP();

                    line = in.readLine();
                }

            }
            catch(IOException e){

                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(
                    objPath.toAbsolutePath() + " doesn't exist");
        }
```

I wrote that code but something is wrong.

intArray[0] is all first integers
intArray[1] is all second integers

But I asked intArray[0] = 1 intArray[1] = 2 intArray[2] = 1 intArray[3] = 4 ... intArray[25] = 10

How can I do? Some help :)

Edit : I'm going to use intArray as parameter

Edit2 : I fixed part of code that are not understood

Edit3 : Thanks for useful coding @xagaffar . Another thing is that if 11 is in the text top of the file, how can we do that instead of `BridgeInGraph graph_obj = new BridgeInGraph(11);`

```
11
1  2
1  4
1  5
2  3
2  6
3  6
4  5
4  7
5  7
7  8
7  9
8  10
9  10


BridgeInGraph graph_obj = new BridgeInGraph(11);
//BridgeInGraph graph_obj = new BridgeInGraph(stringArray[x]);

        Path objPath = Paths.get("graph.txt");
        if (Files.exists(objPath)){

            File objFile = objPath.toFile();
            try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(objFile))){
                String line = in.readLine();

                while(line != null){

                    String[] linesFile = new String[] {line};

                    String[] stringArray = line.split("\\s+");


                    graph_obj.add_edges_to_vertex(
                            Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0]),
                            Integer.parseInt(stringArray[1]));

                    line = in.readLine();
                }
                System.out.println("Bridges in  Graphs ");
                graph_obj.getCutVertices();
                System.out.println("Points:");
                graph_obj.AP();
            }
            catch(IOException e){

                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(
                    objPath.toAbsolutePath() + " doesn't exist");
        }
```

Comment: what do you do with `intArray` after the `for` loop ? currently, you're not doing anything with it after you populate it with the integers.

Comment: @Aominè this is graph algorithm project. So I'm going to take integers from text and do graph.

Comment: You're not answering my question. what do you do with the `intArray` after the for loop? something that you're not showing us? or nothing like the code is shown?

Comment: @O.Aytar `intArray` is local to the loop. It doesn't exist outside the loop.

Comment: You can't put everything in an array here: you need to use a list, because you don't know how many elements there are before you start reading the file.

Comment: *P.S.* GUYS, THIS IS MY HOMEWORK, PLEASE DO IT FOR ME!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Scanner`, it contains methods to read `nextInt()`:

```
public static void main(Strin... arg) {
    int[] numbers = readNumbers(new FileInputStream(new File("graph.txt")));
}

public static int[] readNumbers(InputStream in) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while (scan.hasNext())
        numbers.add(scan.nextInt());

    return toIntArray(numbers);
}

private static int[] toIntArray(List<Integer> numbers) {
    int i = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[numbers.size()];

    for (int num : numbers)
        arr[i++] = num;

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I must take integers from text file

Comment: @O.Aytar not problem, do use `FileInputStream` to read a text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Path objPath = Paths.get("graph.txt");
    if (Files.exists(objPath)){
        File objFile = objPath.toFile();
        try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(objFile))){
            String line = in.readLine();
            List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

            while(line != null){
                String[] stringArray = line.split("\\s+");
                for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
                    String numberAsString = stringArray[i];
                    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(numberAsString));
                }

                line = in.readLine();
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(
                objPath.toAbsolutePath() + " doesn't exist");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you are declaring your obj_graph inside the loop, you basically creating a new object in each cycle. Declare it outside of the loop.

The second problem is that you are accessing array elements (intArray[2], intArray[3]) that are not in it.

This should solve your problem.

```
    BridgeInGraph graph_obj = new BridgeInGraph(11);

    Path objPath = Paths.get("graph.txt");
    if (Files.exists(objPath)) {

        File objFile = objPath.toFile();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(objFile))) {
            String line = in.readLine();

            while (line != null) {

                String[] stringArray = line.split("\\s+");
                graph_obj.add_edges_to_vertex(
                       Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0]),
                       Integer.parseInt(stringArray[1]));

                line = in.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println(
                objPath.toAbsolutePath() + " doesn't exist");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful idea but not my answer

Comment: I guess you didn't get my question. My question is that I want to take all integer as different array element. Such as stringArray[2] is 1, stringArray[6] 2 or stringArray[25] is 10 like that. Look at the top of the page, there is a text file.

Comment: @O.Aytar you can't do that inside your while loop - in.readLine() returns just 1 line from the file.

Comment: and what's the point in collecting all lines in 1 array anyway? It's really a redundant and against the whole idea of using loops..

Comment: you may be right my friend, then I've question :  if 11 is in text file, how can we do that instead of `BridgeInGraph graph_obj = new BridgeInGraph(11);`

Comment: Not sure what do you mean.. I don't know what the BridgeInGraph class looks like, so can't say much. But if it's supposed to work with how you describe it, then the above code should do it, try to run it.. If it doesn't work, then there are other problems with other parts of the code

Comment: I just asked `BridgeInGraph graph_obj = new BridgeInGraph(stringArray[2 or something]);` instead of `BridgeInGraph graph_obj = new BridgeInGraph(11);` same text file same array, only different is `11` number is top of the text file

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Declare graph_obj at the top, but don't instantiate it. Then inside the try block when you call in.readLine() first time get the line, parseInt it (you must have single number on the first line), use that number to instantiate  (graph_obj = new BridgeInGraph();)